# Azure Monitor Workbooks. Auto-update of hidden tiles

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring, azure-monitor-workbooks

I have developed a Workbook merging data from couple of small Queries together. These queries (tiles) are hidden (conditionally visible: condition : 1=2). It seems to be working during development an manual run of the queries. But when I open the workbook another day in read mode the resulting query (merge) is not going to be started/finished (?). It shows as it would be running but it lasts endlessly till I run the source-queries manually, and then rerun the resulting query.
It looks like pretty standard configuration, why it doesn't work for me?
[source-queires](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX2Q6.png)
[merge query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bra3v.png)

Comment: [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBoL1.png)

Comment: [merge query hanging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/92vN1.png)

Comment: After "Run" all the source queries and "Cancel" and "Run" of the merge query - everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

In workbooks, queries will run if they are

a) visible
-or-
b) referenced by a merge that is visible

We currently do not support merges referencing *hidden merges*.

But fear not!  A lot of people miss that a merge step can actually do many merges at once, so it is almost never need merges that reference another merge.